# Ruby on Rails, Split Model into Two Controllers/Forms, but update action calling parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a model that for edit/update actions only is logically split into two forms. The model is Venue. I created app/controllers/venues_controller.rb. The two sub-forms are Details and Policies, so I created app/controllers/venues/details_controller.rb and app/controllers/venues/policies_controller.rb, as well as their corresponding views. The child controllers do inherit from VenuesController. I added the venues namespace to my routes, so it now looks like:
    resources :venues
    namespace :venues do
        :details, :policies
    end

The routes work correctly, the correct views load, the "edit" action on the sub-controllers is called correctly. However, in the sub-views, I'm using the RESTful form_for(@venue), so when the form is POSTed (PUT) it is going to venue_path, not venue_details_path.

I looked at the docs for form_for and can't figure out a way to keep my sub-forms restful. You can add a token for a namespace a la form_for([:namespace, @model]), but in my case, the model name is the namespace, so it's inverted.

I really don't want to split the model itself, since that has other implications that would be harder to address.

So far, I see two solutions, both of which I don't like:
1. Let both views POST to VenuesController#update and deal with any differences there (more lame controller code)
2. Use form_tag and _tag helpers (more lame view code)

Am I missing something obvious? Is there something different I can do in the routes, or is there another way to call form_for?

I've scanned some posts about Presenter and Conductor patterns but they don't seem to fit this problem. I've read a few stackoverflow threads about whether creating two controllers for one model koscher (it is), but nothing about this specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found it. form_for(@venue, :url => venues_detail_path(@venue)). Gotta love Rails.